# Deprecated PagerAdapter.instantiateItem() method

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I'm curious as to why `instantiateItem` was deprecated in favor of it's newer version. The change is that it now receives `ViewGroup` in stead of a more general `View`.

**Deprecated method**

```
public Object instantiateItem (View container, int position)
```

**New method**

```
public Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position)
```

Note: This change also happened to `destroyItem`, `startUpdate`, `finishUpdate` & `setPrimaryItem`.

Comment: I started doing Android programming before instantiateItem(View, int) was in vogue, but from what I have read about it, the reasoning was that it was not as friendly to using Fragments, hence the need for use of ViewGroup

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that it was done because those methods are always called with a `ViewGroup` rather than the more general `View`.  As such, providing the parameter as a `ViewGroup` is a convenience, allowing developers to avoid always checking and casting the input.  So instead of seeing this code over and over:

```
ViewGroup parent;
if (container instanceof ViewGroup) {
    parent = (ViewGroup) container;
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("container must be a ViewGroup");
}
```

The implementer can simply use `container` directly.

And, in fact, you can see that this is exactly the reason in the [commit message from Adam Powell](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/583d8a1ff64c7c59dd4e11759f3d8e994ce878d9%5E!/):

> Bug 5327146 - ViewPager API tweaks and docs
>
> PagerAdapter previously took View instances as parameters to several
>   of its methods leading to lots of casting to ViewGroup in adapter
>   implementations.
>
> Change these to take ViewGroups. Default implementation calls through
>   to deprecated stubs with the existing signatures, allowing current
>   adapters to keep working unmodified.

Comment: Nice. Did you find the commit doing git log on PageAdapter.java on a local git copy or is there a way to browse for changes on the Android sources online?

Comment: I used the Android SDK Search chrome extension, which adds a direct link to the source code from the online SDK docs and dug further from there: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin

Answer (score 1):

The thing is container for ViewPager is supposed to contain other views and it really doesn't make any sense to pass an object of general view in that method as the container is always going to be a ViewGroup.